# RecyclerView infinite Scroll with Volley

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-recyclerview

Im trying to create a Infinite Scroll RecyclerView. Im working with PHP and MySQL. In my PHP script request for 2 Items everytime the RecyclerView reaches the bottom.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM beichten WHERE id BETWEEN ($id+1) AND ($id+2)";
```

Is it possible to do this with Volley?

I created a Class that triggers my request class everytime the RecyclerView reaches the bottom.

```
private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0) {
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (lastVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1){
                Toast.makeText(Menue.this, "BOTTOM", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                requestJsonObject();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

It works but the RecyclerView loads again and shows only the 2 new loaded Objects.

```
private void requestJsonObject() {

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, getbeichtenphp, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
                Gson mGson = builder.create();
                List<ItemObject> posts = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();
                posts = Arrays.asList(mGson.fromJson(response, ItemObject[].class));
                adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(Menue.this, posts);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
                    @Override


                    public void onScrollChange(View view, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {
                        isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView);
                    }
                });

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();

                parameters.put("id", String.valueOf(adapter.getItemCount()));

                return parameters;
            }
        };
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: You're creating a new `Adapter` instance with just the current response items each time. Instead, add those items to the list in your current `Adapter`.

Answer (score 0):

I face this problem before,instead of pass the `id` parameter to my API,I add the `id` it to my URL

**Define your URL like this**

```
private String getbeichtenphp = "http://your/url/here/?id="
```

**Then at volley you pass the id value to the URL.**

```
 //pass the id as a parameter to your requestJsonObject function here
 private void requestJsonObject(int id) {

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
                                                                           //add your id here
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, getbeichtenphp + id, new Response.Listener<String>() {
```

**For the initial call for this function should be**

```
requestJsonObject(0)
```

By doing this,the id will keep adding up,end up fetching the new 2 item every Volley Request.

One more thing,you should use `GET` method as your `Request.method` and get value at php as well instead of using `POST` method.

Look at this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtVHvifaKC4),I think you will have clearer picture.